# show that if every sequence of $K$ has a subsequence converging to a point in $K$, show that $K$ is closed and bounded

Tags: real-analysis

I am able to prove the closed part of the proof but I'm having trouble proving the bounded part.

We can use proof by contradiction and say suppose $K$ is not bounded. 
Then $x_n \to \infty$, and there is a subsequence $x_{n_k} \to x$ in $K$ by assumption. But an unbounded sequence can still have a converging subsequence. I'm not sure how to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

For $x_{n}\rightarrow\infty$, this sequence is not only unbounded, but converges to $\infty$ in the extended real sense, its subsequence must converge to $\infty$, this can be seen by $x_{n}>M$ for all $n\geq N$, then for $K$ such that all $k\geq n_{K}\geq N$, then $x_{n_{k}}>M$.

To prove that it is closed, use sequential characterization of closedness of a set, for $(x_{n})\subseteq K$ is such that $x_{n}\rightarrow x$, since there is a subsequence $(x_{n_{k}})$ such that $x_{n_{k}}\rightarrow y$ for some $y\in K$, then $x_{n_{k}}\rightarrow x$, so $x=y$, and hence $x\in K$.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, there are unbounded sequences with convergent subsequences.  So just make sure this doesn't happen.  Choose $x_1$ so that $|x_1|>1$.  Then inductively choose $x_n$ so that $|x_n|>|x_{n-1}|+1$.  Then the sequence has the property that no subsequence is Cauchy, and therefore no subsequence can converge.

Comment: Without using recursion, just choose $x_n$ such that $|x_n|>n. $ For any bounded interval $J$ the set $\{n: x_n\in J\}$ is finite so $(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ has no convergent sub-sequences.